# Boofcv Video Mosaic Example compile error

Tags: boofcv

I added `"boofcv\evaluation\visualization\src"` to my normal java project in eclipse. I added precompiled libraries too. All other java files are fine except for this single line:

[image]

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The constructor VideoProcessAppBase<I>(int, (color ? ImageType.ms(3, imageType) : ImageType.single(imageType))) is undefined
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageType<MultiSpectral<ImageSingleBand>> to Class<I>
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageType<MultiSpectral<ImageSingleBand>> to Class<I>
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageType<ImageSingleBand> to Class<I>
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ImageType<ImageSingleBand> to Class<I>

at boofcv.alg.sfm.d2.VideoStitchBaseApp.<init>(VideoStitchBaseApp.java:97)
at boofcv.alg.sfm.d2.VideoMosaicSequentialPointApp.<init>(VideoMosaicSequentialPointApp.java:55)
at boofcv.alg.sfm.d2.VideoMosaicSequentialPointApp.main(VideoMosaicSequentialPointApp.java:137)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed 
I used these to fix Errors :

1. The evaluation library was not in pre-compiled libs.I download it and add it
2. I deleted other java files in the same package specially the one which had error . There is only one java file in my project